# 9 patch makes a view really huge

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

Here's how it looks without a 9-patch in background :

[image]

here's the code for xml's top :

```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rlTop"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >


       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="16dp"
           android:src="@mipmap/icon"/>
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="ВЫБЕРИТЕ МАРШРУТ"
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:textSize="20sp"/>
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:paddingRight="16dp"
           android:gravity="center_vertical |end"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tvCompany"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textColor="@color/black"

               android:text="Васильевское ПАТП"/>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textColor="@color/black"
               android:text="ГЛ384Н3Т"/>
        </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

but when I insert a 9patch as a background it distorts the whole view :

```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rlTop"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/route2"
     >
```

[image]

here's the 9-patch :

[image]

What's the problem and how do I keep the view's size? May be it's a 9-patch that is wrong?

Comment: `route2` is your 9 patch ?

Comment: exactly. it is also attached

Comment: add `android:padding="0dp"` in your `RelativeLayout` section

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya doesn't change anything

Comment: Okay .Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's the same result